# Given a string, count the number of words ending in 'y' or 'z'

Tags: java, string

Given a string, count the number of words ending in `'y'` or `'z'` -- so the `'y'` in "heavy" and the `'z'` in "fez" count, but not the `'y'` in "yellow" (not case sensitive). We'll say that a `y` or `z` is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it. (Note: `Character.isLetter(char)` tests if a char is an alphabetic letter.)

For example,

```
    countYZ("fez day") → 2
    countYZ("day fez") → 2
    countYZ("day fyyyz") → 2
    countYZ("day yak") → 1  
    countYZ("day:yak") → 1      
    countYZ("!!day--yaz!!") → 2
```

But I'm failing these cases:

```
countYZ("fez day") → should be 2 but Im getting 1           
countYZ("day fez") → should be 2 but Im getting 1    
countYZ("day fyyyz") → should be 2 but Im getting 1
```

Could smb take a look and see whats wrong with my code? THanks in advance!

```
public int countYZ(String str) {

  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
    if((str.charAt(i) == 'y' || str.charAt(i) == 'z')
     && !(Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i + 1)))){
        count++;
     } 
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include logic for the corner case of the word being at the very end of the String.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! @Xirema.. I'll accept the answer in a few mins

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged that question with `regex`, here's a solution using [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[yz]\\b").matcher(str);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find())
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Here, the expression `"[yz]\\b"` means "y or z, followed by a word boundary", i.e. it matches whenever there is an y or z at the end of a word. Just count the matches.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for this task:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
      int counter;
      String regex = "[YyZz](?!\\p{IsAlphabetic})"; 
      java.util.regex.Pattern yzEnd = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex);
      java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = yzEnd.matcher(str);
      for (counter = 0; matcher.find(); counter++);
      return counter;
      
}
```

**p{IsAlphabetic}** matches the characters p{IsAlphabetic} literally (case sensitive)